# How to modify GetAllDetails action on application controller to retrieve all details where headerid=1?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I work on `EF core 7 blazor`  . I face issue I can't call Details model  from application page to get all Data for details model .

meaning I need to display details data as list on application page where Header Id = 1 on action `GetAllDetails`.

so when call `Application/GetAllDetails`  I will get all Details contain ID AND DetailsName from model details
where Header Id=1

details models

```
public class Details
{
public int ID { get; set; }
public string DetailsName { get; set; }
public int HeaderId { get; set; }
}
```

application model

```
 public class Applications
    {
        [Key]
        public int ApplicationID { get; set; }
        public string Section { get; set;}
        public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
     }
```

on controller application

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ApplicationController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IapplicationService _IapplicationService;
        public ApplicationController(IapplicationService iapplicationService)
        {
            _IapplicationService = iapplicationService;
        }



 [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetAllDetails()
    {
//How to get all details
        return Ok();
       
    }
```

Comment: If you use mvc controller (`ApplicationController : Controller`), you don't need to add `[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you try

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetAllDetailsSection()
        {
            var query = from u in _context.Details
                    where u.HeaderId == 1
                    select u;
            return Ok(query);
        }
```

I test in my demo and get the result as:

[image]